# OpenCascade Step file UserDefined property reading

Tags: opencascade

I recently approached OpenCascade and I have
some difficulty both understanding the framework and developing in C++.

I would like to export the step file in a proprietary format.
What I'm missing to conclude is the possibility of exporting the
userdefined properties associated with each node (key and value).
I can traverse the model in and get the list of these properties

```
Handle(StepBasic_GeneralProperty) gp =Handle(StepBasic_GeneralProperty)::DownCast(entity); 
string id = gp->Id()->ToCString();
string name = gp->Name()->ToCString();
string desc = gp->Description()->ToCString();
```

but I can't get the value of the property and know which instance it is connected to.